# Why can't Kotlin infer the parameter and return type of a function?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the end branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab).

I think I can simplify it, so I write Code B and Code C, but in fact, they are wrong, why?

BTW, Code D can be compiled.

**Code A**

```
val onPeopleChanged: (Int) -> Unit = { viewModel.updatePeople(it) }
```

**Code B**

```
val onPeopleChanged = { viewModel.updatePeople(it) }
```

**Code C**

```
val onPeopleChanged = {it -> viewModel.updatePeople(it) }
```

**Code D**

```
val onPeopleChanged = {it:Int -> viewModel.updatePeople(it) }
```

Comment: I think there is a better option `val onPeopleChanged = viewModel::updatePeople`

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation it seems that Kotlin cannot infer the types in the lambda expression: refer to example 4 here https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/02_Lambdas

Comment: I do think example 4 is a bit different though. because it can't possibly infer it there because it's unknown which type has the `uppercase()` function. In the example here it should be perfectly clear that `it` must be an Int because `viewModel.updatePeople` expects an Int

Comment: I think @Stefan is right with example 4: isn't a lambda with no explicit types either inside of it, outside of it, or at both places, by definition a function with no arguments? And therefore it is irrelevant that updatePeople expects an Int because _it_ is not an argument of the lambda. When you look at the suggestions of the IDE, it does suggest to create a local variable called 'it', there is no option 'Replace _it_ with explicit parameter', and on the braces it suggest to create an anonymous function with no argument.